# Trying to activate ec_sys

Tags: drivers, kernel, msi, 23.10

OS: Ubuntu 23.10

Hardware: PC based on motherboard MSI A520M-A PRO and AMD 5700G CPU

Secure boot disabled:

```
sudo mokutil --sb
SecureBoot disabled
```

ec_sys IS NOT a builtin kernel module, checked with `grep ec_sys /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin` - nothing returned.

Created file /etc/modprobe.d/isw-ec_sys.conf with content

```
options ec_sys write_support=1
```

Created file /etc/modules-load.d/isw-ec_sys.conf with content

```
ec_sys
```

Rebooted. After reboot executed

```
sudo modprobe ec_sys write_support=1
```

`modinfo ec_sys` shows

```
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/kernel/drivers/acpi/ec_sys.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    ACPI EC sysfs access driver
author:         Thomas Renninger <trenn@suse.de>
srcversion:     6BF25094433A90516CBD9ED
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ec_sys
vermagic:       6.5.0-10-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        72:68:0C:9F:00:8A:A6:96:1B:CA:7A:2A:2C:FF:45:D4:8A:E7:C4:BB
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      99:4A:15:0C:03:90:E2:80:D9:D3:34:39:B0:D5:1D:F2:E5:8B:BB:24:
                05:D4:9F:64:6C:64:AA:8B:6F:6D:97:99:47:38:5B:EA:FC:66:0A:EC:
                9D:F2:E0:37:1F:F2:40:18:F9:D2:90:71:4E:E6:E4:87:6E:2F:C7:70:
                E6:F4:38:B3:B9:F4:FF:6E:60:68:60:AF:70:E0:98:B8:65:7C:CB:49:
                B6:6B:54:20:36:19:E2:A3:0D:92:BE:4E:2E:98:81:95:2B:F9:E4:9A:
                A8:B3:24:00:4F:67:97:40:F6:64:54:4A:06:68:86:1B:A4:FA:3D:B8:
                C8:FB:31:5B:E1:BC:FA:8A:3D:AC:8D:19:C6:3C:9B:49:F4:B6:10:97:
                89:05:11:8E:94:02:86:88:E0:9A:37:B6:53:3B:2A:23:8E:21:DB:C6:
                5B:23:44:69:CB:0C:CD:5C:DD:22:5E:F4:CD:4A:D3:C3:14:DC:F4:18:
                91:EC:6C:BF:5C:B6:9F:26:54:56:54:38:3B:84:6F:1B:F0:90:41:DE:
                58:11:D3:ED:3F:01:F7:F7:77:8A:1C:BF:3C:8A:9F:64:93:4B:36:93:
                F0:A1:47:AF:65:F6:A0:CE:C6:D5:7C:6F:C5:18:84:DB:88:C3:12:FF:
                84:24:15:F8:9A:53:12:14:BA:B7:E1:2D:E6:3E:5C:55:71:C0:F8:B6:
                0C:D5:4C:68:E0:03:FC:48:09:C7:42:35:F1:51:52:29:2E:66:40:FE:
                55:C4:40:7D:BA:83:B7:FD:43:61:1B:E4:86:D9:74:8D:DA:08:00:49:
                F0:D0:D4:82:54:9F:4C:23:3B:85:87:56:05:15:7D:29:0B:FC:8A:85:
                29:E7:1B:84:F7:5D:DA:2D:83:66:51:85:C5:A9:12:FF:51:42:99:C5:
                4D:43:DA:C9:E8:F7:2B:2C:50:E7:D3:8D:B5:33:0D:7E:D8:99:0B:FD:
                A0:11:2E:BA:F9:2F:E7:6F:58:37:B8:13:26:EC:2B:A6:0E:B7:DB:D4:
                36:81:20:4D:3C:90:CC:FA:AE:17:93:C9:71:E9:80:04:3B:87:10:2F:
                0D:D4:07:63:D5:2A:63:B6:AF:A4:D5:84:99:FF:74:9F:24:26:D7:E2:
                4B:25:EE:03:E1:F5:6B:89:D0:A9:BD:9A:DA:E8:D0:4E:B6:73:1A:3F:
                B7:CE:D2:21:CD:2F:39:03:F5:3A:68:6B:35:38:B9:C1:0D:9C:24:00:
                FB:4D:AA:67:F1:C2:E6:97:8A:07:AA:C8:B0:21:F0:14:A5:3F:2A:56:
                6D:12:54:ED:F5:71:3E:E6:E5:28:8C:80:95:C4:45:43:6B:BE:F8:7C:
                2D:F3:CC:71:E0:29:6A:68:0D:CB:A7:E3
parm:           write_support:Dangerous, reboot and removal of battery may be needed. (bool)
```

`lsmod | grep ec` shows

```
ec_sys                 12288  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   192512  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   122880  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          12288  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
snd_hda_codec         212992  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          147456  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               196608  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
cec                    94208  1 drm_display_helper
rc_core                77824  1 cec
snd                   143360  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

`cat /sys/module/ec_sys/parameters/write_support` shows

```
Y
```

Debugfs mounted:

```
mount | grep debug
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

But still there is no directory /sys/kernel/debug/ec/ :

```
sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/ec/
ls: cannot access '/sys/kernel/debug/ec/': No such file or directory
sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io
ls: cannot access '/sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io': No such file or directory
```

How to fix this issue?